# Trying to add custom font in three.js

Tags: javascript, django, three.js

Trying to add my own custom font, but nothing shows up I think it's crashing??, is there a way to get three.js to render my font: [Custom Font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of5qE.png)

"{%static "js/pink.json"%}" --> this is django's template tagging.

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

var font = loader.load( "{%static "js/pink.json"%}", function ( font ) {

var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( "My Text", {

    font: font,

    size: 3,
    height: 3,


} );

var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x000000 } );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, textMaterial );
mesh.position.set( x, y, z );

scene.add( mesh );
```

I get these errors as well:
[Browser crashing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhDrW.png)
and
[Duplicate Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Q3x.png)

Comment: Did you use https://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/ to convert the font to json?

Comment: Yes note line 3 s/pink.json, yes it has been converted to json.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you very much @prisoner849, it's work !

Link to convert files in JSON : gero3.github.io/facetype.js

I converted a .ttf file to an .json file and it's work perfectly with the "THREE.FontLoader" of "Three js" !

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load( 'font_file_name.json', function ( font ) { ... }
```